# Can't access Glacier using AWS CLI

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to access AWS Glacier (from the command line on Ubuntu 14.04) using something like:

```
aws glacier list-vaults -
```

rather than

```
aws glacier list-vaults --account-id 123456789
```

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/list-vaults.html) suggests that this should be possible:

> You can specify either the AWS Account ID or optionally a '-', in
> which case Amazon Glacier uses the AWS Account ID associated with the
> credentials used to sign the request.

Unless "credentials used to sign the request" means that I have to explicitly include credentials in the command, rather than rely on my .aws/credentials file, I would expect this to work. Instead, I get:

> aws: error: argument --account-id is required

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: By the way, I should note that commands will work when I use the full --account-id argument, and that I'm using the most recent AWS CLI package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-` is supposed to be passed as the value of `--account-id`, so like

```
aws glacier list-vaults --account-id -
```

`--account-id` is in fact a required option.

Answer (score -1):

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glacier/list-vaults.html

Says that "--account-id" is a required parameter for the glacier section of the full aws api.  A little wierd, but documented. So yay.

Comment: This does not provide anything new compared to the accepted answer from nearly 7 years ago.